# Prevent multiple foreign key references to same row in primary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing Employees all of whom have an ID; I'm referencing this ID in two other tables (Salesman, Mechanic) via a foreign key. What I want to ensure is that an employee is either a mechanic or a salesman, but never both. In other words, I want to associate this logic with my foreign keys:

[image]

[image]

How would I integrate logic like that into a table? I'm a SQL beginner, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] 
(
    Number INT NOT NULL, 
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY(Number)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Salesman] 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY(ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee](ID)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mechanic] 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY(ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee](ID)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one-of relationship and it is tricky to implement in SQL.  Here is one method:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
    EmployeeId INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    EmployeeType VARCHAR(32)
    -- ...
    CHECK (EmployeeType IN ('Mechanic', 'SalesPerson')),
    UNIQUE (EmployeeType, EmployeeId)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesPerson] 
(
    EmployeeId INT PRIMAY KEY,
    -- ...
    EmployeeType as (CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 'Salesperson')) PERSISTED,
    FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeType, EmployeeId) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee](EmployeeType, EmployeeId)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mechanic] (
    EmployeeId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EmployeeType as (CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 'Mechanic')) PERSISTED,
    -- ...
    FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeType, EmployeeId) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee](EmployeeType, EmployeeId)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/73633) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating the code.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly, the idea is that when I insert something into [dbo].[Mechanic] it will send the string 'Mechanic' along and the primary table will then check if that matches what is in the EmployeeType column?

Comment: @nick . . . Yes.  As a note, this also wastes space storing the strings on each row of the table (the `persisted` attribute).  For that reason, you might want to make it a single character value.  This introduces redundancy, but you don't have to use a trigger -- I consider that worth the extra space.